# swift2 use of undeclared type even though type is embedded

Tags: swift, xcode, function, parameters, local-variables

I know this problem has come up before but I found the others difficult to interpret. My function is as follows:

```
override func update(Enem: SKSpriteNode,currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

}
```

However I get an error of:

> 'use of undeclared type' over the currentTime: NSTimeInterval

Even though it is embedded (I only got this error after I added the 2nd parameter `Enem` which I was sending from another function because it was a local variable).

Comment: OK, your grammar is brilliant but can we answer the question now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 2 error: "extra argument in call", when trying to send variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39280865/swift-2-error-extra-argument-in-call-when-trying-to-send-variable)